# Преобразование XSLT не работает в IE9

Tags: javascript, html, xml, xslt

[Ссылка на пример](http://www.w3schools.com/xsl/xsl_client.asp)

Как запустить этот код в IE9?

Comment: В чем именно проблема? Какие результаты отладки?

Comment: IE11 пишет SCRIPT5: Отказано в доступе.

Comment: IE9 пишет SCRIPT16389: Таблица стилей не содержит элемент документ.  Пустая таблица, или неправильно отформатированный документ XML.

Comment: Firefox всё правильно отображает.

Comment: Во-первых, не используйте xslt-трансформацию на клиенте, используйте преобразование на сервере. Во-вторых, не используйте ActiveX - эта технология, мягко говоря, устарела. В-третьих, вы ничего не путаете? Только IE может использовать ActiveX (если разрешено в настройках). FF и другие браузеры на это не способны.

Comment: В силу архитектуры системы мне необходимо сделать это преобразование на клиенте. Сейчас у всех клиентов стоит IE9.